# piwik log import invalid log lines

Tags: analytics, matomo, log-analysis

I'm new to piwik and trying to import a bunch of logs.  I need help with the log-format-regex. A sample line from the log is:

> "1.1.1.1" 2.2.2.2 - myuser [09/Dec/2012:04:03:29 -0500] "GET /signon.html HTTP/1.1" 304 "http://www.example.com/example" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1"

my log format regex looks like this:

```
--log-format-regex='\\\\"(?P<ip>\\\\S+)\\\\" \\\\S+ \\\\S+ \\\\S+ \\\\[(?P<date>.*?) (?P<timezone>.*?)\\\\] \\\\"\\\\S+ (?P<path>.*?) \\\\S+\\\\" (?P<status>\\\\S+) (?P<length>\\\\S+) \\\\"(?P<referrer>.*?)\\\\" \\\\"(?P<user_agent>.*?)\\\\"'
```

I'm consistently getting all "requests ignored" and "invalid log lines".  For example:

### Logs import summary

```
0 requests imported successfully
0 requests were downloads
236252 requests ignored:
    236252 invalid log lines
    0 requests done by bots, search engines, ...
    0 HTTP errors
    0 HTTP redirects
    0 requests to static resources (css, js, ...)
    0 requests did not match any known site
    0 requests did not match any requested hostname
```

How can I fix log-format-regex?

tia,
dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When importing with the `piwik` (resp. `matomo`) log imported you can issue the `--debug` option twice, which will spew the invalid line.

Here is an example of a script that shows it (but this is my preferred log format)

```
python /opt/piwik.git/misc/log-analytics/import_logs.py \
    --debug --debug \
    --url=$piwik_site \
    --log-format-regex='(?P<host>\S+) (?P<ip>\S+) \S+ \[(?P<date>.*?) (?P<timezone>.*?)\] "\S+ (?P<path>.*?) \S+" (?P<status>\d+) (?P<length>\d+) "(?P<referrer>.*?)"$'
    --add-sites-new-hosts \
    --enable-http-errors \
    --enable-http-redirects \
    --enable-static \
    --strip-query-string \
    --show-progress \
    --show-progress-delay 2 \
    --recorders $cpu \
    "$1"
```

$1 is the name of the file I'm importing from (my Apache, Nginx and Lighttpd boxen all use this same format).

The output will have a few lines that look like this:

```
2013-09-03 19:42:34,145: [DEBUG] Invalid line detected (line did not match): edoceo.com 10.0.0.1 - [03/Sep/2013:16:41:03 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "Some Bad Robot v0.1"
```

And those show you what's invalid, and provide the clues on how to tune/tweak your regexp.

I've got a few details of my setup at http://edoceo.com/howto/piwik#import